# Block title not show for exposed filter

Tags: views, blocks, theming

My exposed filter's form is placed in a region, within a block. I have activated the *Config Block > Display Title* option (I also overrode the title) but I see no title (a `h2` should be added on top of the form, like it is displayed in other custom blocks below the filter, I suppose)

```
<div class="views-exposed-form bef-exposed-form 
            contextual-region block block-views 
            block-views-exposed-filter-blockcar-model-view-page-1" 
     data-drupal-selector="views-exposed-form-car-model-view-page-1" 
     id="block-exposedformcar-model-viewpage-1">
    <!-- A H2 with the title doesn't show up here like in other blocks -->
    <div data-contextual-
        id="block:block=exposedformcar_model_viewpage_1:langcode=en|
        entity.view.edit_form:view=car_model_view:location=exposed_filter
        &amp;name=car_model_view&amp;display_id=page_1&amp;langcode=en" 
    class="contextual" role="form">
        <div class="content">
            <!-- The form with the filters -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is this happening? Could I add the title within a `form_alter` hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue and there appears to be a patch for it: https://www.drupal.org/node/2720101